# how to fill DataGridView with json lis

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Hi I am using this function to show  json in DataGridView but the problem is I have a list in the json file , this list doesn't display data in the grid

```
   void show_data()
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        dataGrid.DataSource = all_date;          
    }
```

my json file is as this

```html
[{"Name":"350SC250-14","Fy":33.0,"GFy":false,"T":0.0713,"GT":false,"D":2.5,"Stud_D":1.5,"C":0.0,"B":3.5,"GB":false,"Manufacturer":"BIDDLE","CFS_File":"350SC250-14.cfss","Sub_SectionCount":0,"Sub_Section1":"","Sub_Section2":"","Sub_Section3":"","SectionType":3,"Configuration":0,"SectionParts":[{"Length":0.375,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":3.0,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":2.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":3.0,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.5,"Radius":0.1069},{"Length":0.375,"Radius":0.0}]}]
```

my class is bellow

```
 class dataForm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Fy { get; set; }
    public bool GFy { get; set; }
    public double T { get; set; }
    public bool GT { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; }
    public double Stud_D { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public bool GB { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string CFS_File { get; set; }
    public int Sub_SectionCount { get; set; }
    public string Sub_Section1 { get; set; }
    public string Sub_Section2 { get; set; }
    public string Sub_Section3 { get; set; }
    public int SectionType { get; set; }
    public int Configuration { get; set; }
    public List<SectionPart> SectionParts { get; set; }

}
class SectionPart
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
}
```

so how can I diplay this sectionPart list ?

Comment: all_date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dataForm>>(data_from_json);

Comment: Your options are to use a grid control that supports hierarchies like you can find from vendors like Telerik, Infragistics, etc. or split your grid into parent/child views, where clicking on a row in the parent will populate another grid that contains the related list of data.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)  nuget :`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` to your project, and convert JSON to object using `DeserializeObject`

```
    string data_from_json = @"[{'Name':'350SC250 - 14','Fy':33.0,'GFy':false,'T':0.0713,'GT':false,'D':2.5,'Stud_D':1.5,'C':0.0,'B':3.5,'GB':false,'Manufacturer':'BIDDLE','CFS_File':'350SC250 - 14.cfss','Sub_SectionCount':0,'Sub_Section1':'','Sub_Section2':'','Sub_Section3':'','SectionType':3,'Configuration':0,'SectionParts':[{'Length':0.375,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':3.0,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':2.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':3.0,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.5,'Radius':0.1069},{'Length':0.375,'Radius':0.0}]}]";
    dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
    List<dataForm> all_date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dataForm>>(data_from_json);
    dataGrid.DataSource = all_date;
```

to display SectionParts only:

```
 dataGrid.DataSource = all_date[0].SectionParts;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe does not really have anything to do with JSON. The problem is with the Class `dataForm`. I do not like to say “problem” since the issue is fairly easy to understand, once you understand what your code is asking from the grid. The issue is that when the grid is given a `DataSource` like a `List<T>` or `List<dataForm>`, the grid will obligingly map each “primitive” property of the `dataForm` class (or any class `T`) to a column in the grid.

The grid is going to have to do something different when it comes across a property in the class that is a “Collection” or another “Class”. In this case, `dataForm` has a “collection” property …

```
public List<SectionPart> SectionParts { get; set; }
```

In this case the grid is not sophisticated enough to figure this out. It really is not going to know how to put “multiple” values into a single cell. Therefore, the grid will ignore collections as you obviously already know. This same Idea applies if the property in the class is another class… it will not display it.

Bear in mind, as other have commented, there are third-party controls that may have features that will show the collections or classes. Unfortunately, the out of the box `DataGridView` is fairly limited. In most cases, the easiest way to deal with this is in a “Master/Detail” type display, where the first grid displays the class and the second grid displays the collection of the “selected” item in the first grid.

With that said, there are ways to achieve your goal without a lot of work depending on “how” you want to “display” the data to the user. IMHO a master-detail is usually the easiest to implement and is user friendly. Another option, is to “flatten” each of the items in the collection creating a column(s) for each item in the collection. This is much more work and you will possibly end up with many columns and many empty cells… not user friendly. The last option which may work for your case is to create a public property in the `dataForm` class that “exposes” the `SectionParts` collection as a single string.

Example: in this case, the `SectionPart` class has two (2) properties.

```
public double Length { get; set; }
public double Radius { get; set; }
```

To help later, let’s override the `ToString` method to return the two values as a single string. Something like…

```
public override string ToString() {
  return "L: " + Length + " R: " + Radius;
}
```

Moving to the `dataForm` class there is a “collection” of the `SectionPart` objects. To display ALL the section parts into a single cell we need to create a single string from ALL the section parts. Each part will be on a single line using the `SectionPart`s `ToString` method we added above. To make this “single” string display in the grid, we need to add a new property to the `dataForm` class that returns this “list of parts” as a single string. This property may look like…

```
public string SectionPartsList {
  get {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (SectionPart sp in SectionParts) {
      sb.AppendLine(sp.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}.
```

You may need to adjust the grids rows height to accommodate, however, in my test, if you simply hover your cursor over the cell the list will display.

Lastly, for completeness, let us assume, that instead of a “List” of `SectionParts` the class had a single instance of this class.

```
public SectionPart SingleSectionPart { get; set; }
```

Again the grid is going to ignore this “class” property when creating the columns in the grid. However, if you wanted those two fields displayed in the grid, then it would be fairly simple to create two properties in the `dataForm` class that simply return those values. In this case, the two properties may look like…

```
public double SP_L {
   get {
    return SingleSectionPart.Length;
  }
}

public double SP_R {
  get {
    return SingleSectionPart.Radius;
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: I am really appreciate your help,I got it .
Thank you again